# C++/Qt Apps on Ovi Store?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, nokia, ovi

Can one develop C++/Qt based application for Symbian and N series phone and upload the same to Ovi store ?.

I hear conflicting stories. I understand the existence of Smart Installer etc.

But my question is as of today can I code and ship apps to Ovi store ?.

If not any clue how long before it becomes a reality ?.

Ankur

**Update: http://ht.ly/1PvcI says mid 2010 is when it ships. I also heard from a Qt Developer that is ships along with 4.7 release. Worse case they say is September 2010**

Comment: I suggest you ask in Forum Nokia since Ovi is a Nokia service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today it is not possible to publish applications developed with Qt in Ovi Store. The problem is, that today very few phones have Qt installed. For this, Nokia created the smart installer, that would be asked to install the correct version of Qt from the internet, but still not stable. Something can be done is to link the application statically, but the executable is something more than 10 mb and passed the capacity constraints Ovi Store. In the near future (after the second half of this year) is expected to SmartInstaller is stable and officially supported by Ovi, which would allow to publish the applications based in Qt Framework!.

Comment: I'm not aware of any QT port for Symbian and I don't expect from Apple to have one done soon. But, accidentally, your answer does apply pretty well to Qt's status. ;)

Comment: QT = Qt from Nokia, Not QuickTime!. And you know that i am talking in the response!. Qt Reference Documentation example of use Qt term in capital letter:
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT
QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_QT

"QT
The values stored in the QT variable control which of the Qt modules are used by your project.

The table below shows the options that can be used with the QT variable and the features that are associated with each of them..."

Anyway as it seems more appropriate to use "Qt" ;)

Comment: Is this still valid? This list looks like Qt is on much more devices now: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0/index.html#platform-compatability

Comment: The answer refer to the possibility to submit applications based in Qt to the  OVI store!. Not the availability of Qt for the devices!. thanks anyway for your information!.

Comment: i'd just make this note: i have a Qt based app published on the Ovi Store. So, the answer needs to be updated to say that you can, in fact, ship apps written using Qt (which means for all Symbian^3 devices, as well as the N9)

Answer (score 1):

Like Jordenysp pointed out, there are hardly any Symbian phones which have qt preinstalled. N8 is the first and it hasnt reached sales release yet. So, my wild guess is that when N8 is out, you can ship qt apps to ovi store for symbian.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I heard from a nokia developer it's going to take 1-3 months to have the Nokia Smart Installer as non beta release.